# HTML5 Game - Works in IE, Chrome. Fails in FireFox...Until I Navigate to a .mp3 File...Then It Works

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm using a game library (http://html5quintus.com/) to try and make a very simple 2d platformer.  I don't think this is necessarily specific to game development though.  I'm really just trying to play some audio files.

I'm using FireFox 31.0 - (the latest AFAIK).

The audio files I'm dealing with are all .mp3 files.  The line of code that seems to be causing the problem is:

```
  Q.audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
    callback(key,buffer);
  }, errorCallback);
```

The error I get is:

> The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains invalid content which
>   cannot be decoded successfully. localhost : 50796 uncaught exception:
>   Error Loading: jump.mp3

What I find most confusing though, is that if I navigate to the audio file directly (/audio/jump.mp3) - FireFox will play that audio file correctly.

Here's where it gets really weird....AFTER I load any one of the .mp3 files.  If I navigate back to my game and reload it - it suddenly works completely.  All of the sounds/background music work and everything is just like it is in IE and Chrome.  But if I don't manually load a .mp3 file first, it doesn't.

Once the game is working, I can close that tab/open a new tab and visit the URL and it works again.  It seems to continue working fine until I exit FireFox completely.  Then, the game won't work until I first revisit the .mp3 file directly.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like some sort of caching issue.

Comment: @EvanKnowles - I've just tried on another machine on another network to avoid any local caching.  But the behavior is the same in FF 31

Comment: If you haven't already, hit F12 in Firefox, go to network, and reload the page. Look for jump.mp3 and see if it's doing a 200 get or not. Also go to Console and reload the page, see if it tells you it can't be found. If there are no problems being reported you may have to download Firebug and do some advanced troubleshooting. A quick Google on this doesn't show a whole lot. Sorry I can't be of much help.

Comment: @JackArbiter - The network tab does not show the .mp3 files being downloaded.  The console shows the error pasted above, for each .mp3 file I have.  After I load any individual .mp3, and reload the page - the console shows nothing and the .mp3 files still don't appear in the network tab.  I can see the images/.js/.css files though.

Comment: This may be specific to the audio encoding of the file. There have been several bugs similar to this one that have been fixed prior to version 31 that mention encoding as a problem. The only other unfixed encoding-specific mention is here: https://github.com/kylestetz/lissajous/issues/1 But he could be talking about 24bit .wav files. Anyway, the browsers are known to handle different sound files differently. Again I doubt I'm being of much help since fixing browser audio issues is like shooting in the dark but if you have control over the nature of the MP3 file it may be worth looking into.

Comment: Anyway, if it can play it directly this likely isn't it but playing it from within a page may have different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project the decoding worked fine for months until this morning. 
So it's not the audio files, it's not a caching issue, this error only 
appears in Firefox (I have v31.0), in other browsers(both desktop and mobile) it works fine. 
So I'd bet that it's a Firefox bug, one that unfortunately I don't have a solution for yet.
Will update if I find something.

Comment: I think you are right - just tried it with FireFox v30 and it worked.  Very frustrating :)

Comment: Same as the way the bug appeared, it disappeared, decoding now works on FF 31

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around (for FireFox 31); if I add a regular audio tag to my static loading page, when the game engine gets around to loading it's resources, FireFox will accept the .mp3 files.

```
<audio src="audio/coin.mp3"></audio>
```

If I include that line everything works on all of the major browsers.  If I remove that line, FireFox 30 works, but FireFox 31 fails :(  Yuck.